# Update a table data in maven + seam

Tags: java, jsf, seam, crud

I want to update a record in user table.. My seam+jsf project configured in maven. I tried to make it but failed more.

I am here to get some favor from you friends. Hope someone will help me.

Thanks in advance..

My update page:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:clrp="http://panorosys.com/products/clrp/taglib"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <ui:composition>
        <div class="panel-content">
            <h:form class="input-list" id="createuser">

                <h:panelGrid border="1" class="creatUserDetailsTable">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Personal Details" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <s:decorate id="firstNameDec" template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                        <ui:define name="label">First Name:</ui:define>
                        <h:inputText tabindex="1" id="firstName" type="text"
                            value="#{currentUser.firstName}" required="true">
                            <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="20" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </s:decorate>

                    <s:decorate id="lastNameDec" template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                        <ui:define name="label">Last Name:</ui:define>
                        <h:inputText tabindex="2" id="lastName" type="text"
                            value="#{currentUser.lastName}" required="true">
                            <f:validateLength maximum="20" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </s:decorate>

                    <s:decorate id="emailIdDec" template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                        <ui:define name="label">Email Id:</ui:define>
                        <h:inputText tabindex="3" id="emailId" type="text"
                            value="#{currentUser.emailAddress}">
                            <f:validateLength maximum="20" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </s:decorate>
                    <s:decorate id="homeNumberDec" template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                        <ui:define name="label">Home Number:</ui:define>
                        <h:inputText tabindex="4" id="homeNumber" type="text"
                            value="#{currentUser.homeNumber}">
                            <f:validateLength maximum="20" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </s:decorate>

                    <s:decorate id="cellNumberDec" template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                        <ui:define name="label">Cell Number:</ui:define>
                        <h:inputText tabindex="5" id="cellNumber" type="text"
                            value="#{currentUser.cellNumber}" required="true">
                            <f:validateLength maximum="20" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </s:decorate>

                    <s:decorate id="officeNumberDec"
                        template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                        <ui:define name="label">Office Number:</ui:define>
                        <h:inputText tabindex="6" id="officeNumber" type="text"
                            value="#{currentUser.officeNumber}">
                            <f:validateLength maximum="20" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </s:decorate>
                </h:panelGrid>


                <h:panelGrid border="1" columns="2" class="createUserAddressTable1">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Address" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:panelGrid border="1" class="createcurrentUserAddressTable">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Residential" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <s:decorate id="residentialAddress1Dec"
                            template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">Address 1:</ui:define>
                            <h:inputText tabindex="7" id="residentialAddress1" type="text"
                                value="#{currentUser.residentialAddress.address1}"
                                required="true">
                                <f:validateLength maximum="20" />
                            </h:inputText>
                        </s:decorate>
                        <s:decorate id="residentialAddress2Dec"
                            template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">Address 2:</ui:define>
                            <h:inputText tabindex="7" id="residentialAddress2" type="text"
                                value="#{currentUser.residentialAddress.address2}"
                                required="true">
                                <f:validateLength maximum="20" />
                            </h:inputText>
                        </s:decorate>
                        <s:decorate id="residentialCityDec"
                            template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">City:</ui:define>
                            <h:inputText tabindex="9" id="residentialCity" type="text"
                                value="#{currentUser.residentialAddress.city}" required="true">
                                <f:validateLength maximum="20" />
                            </h:inputText>
                        </s:decorate>
                        <s:decorate id="residentialCountryDec"
                            template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">Country :</ui:define>
                            <h:inputText tabindex="10"
                                value="#{currentUser.residentialAddress.countryId}"
                                id="residentialCountry" type="text"
                                class="resi-country-class cntry" required="true">
                            </h:inputText>
                        </s:decorate>
                        <s:decorate id="residentialStateDec"
                            template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">State :</ui:define>
                            <h:inputText tabindex="11"
                                value="#{currentUser.residentialAddress.stateId}"
                                id="residentialState" type="text" required="true">
                            </h:inputText>
                        </s:decorate>
                        <s:decorate id="residentialZipcodeDec"
                            template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">Zip code :</ui:define>
                            <h:inputText tabindex="12" id="residentialZipcode" type="text"
                                value="#{currentUser.residentialAddress.zipCode}" required="true">
                                <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="6" />
                            </h:inputText>
                        </s:decorate>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid border="1" class="createUserAddressTable">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Shipping" />
                        </f:facet>

                        <s:decorate id="shippingAddress1Dec"
                            template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">Address 1:</ui:define>
                            <h:inputText tabindex="14" id="shippingAddress1" type="text"
                                value="#{currentUser.shippingAddress.address1}" required="true">
                                <f:validateLength maximum="20" />
                            </h:inputText>
                        </s:decorate>
                        <s:decorate id="shippingAddress2Dec"
                            template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">Address 2:</ui:define>
                            <h:inputText tabindex="15" id="shippingAddress2" type="text"
                                value="#{currentUser.shippingAddress.address2}" required="true">
                                <f:validateLength maximum="20" />
                            </h:inputText>
                        </s:decorate>
                        <s:decorate id="shippingCityDec"
                            template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">City:</ui:define>
                            <h:inputText tabindex="16" id="shippingCity" type="text"
                                value="#{currentUser.shippingAddress.city}" required="true">
                                <f:validateLength maximum="20" />
                            </h:inputText>
                        </s:decorate>
                        <s:decorate id="shippingCountryDec"
                            template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">Country :</ui:define>
                            <h:inputText tabindex="17"
                                value="#{currentUser.shippingAddress.countryId}"
                                id="shippingCountry" type="text"
                                class="shipp-country-class cntry" required="true">
                            </h:inputText>
                        </s:decorate>
                        <s:decorate id="shippingStateDec"
                            template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">State :</ui:define>
                            <h:inputText tabindex="18"
                                value="#{currentUser.shippingAddress.stateId}" id="shippingState"
                                type="text" class="shipp-state-class state" required="true">
                            </h:inputText>
                        </s:decorate>
                        <s:decorate id="shippingZipcodeDec"
                            template="../../../secure/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">Zip code :</ui:define>
                            <h:inputText tabindex="19" id="shippingZipcode" type="text"
                                value="#{currentUser.shippingAddress.zipCode}" required="true">
                                <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="6" />
                            </h:inputText>
                        </s:decorate>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:commandButton value="Update" tabindex="20"
                    action="#{userAction.update}" class="usersubmit">
                    <f:param name="userId" value="#{currentUser.userId}" />
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:form>
            <h:messages globalOnly="true" />
            <s:remote include="currentUserListAction" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function() {
                loadCountries("#{restEasyPath}/lookup/Country/");
                $(".shipp-country-class").val(#{currentUserAction.currentUser.shippingAddress.countryId});
                $(".resi-country-class").val(#{currentUserAction.currentUser.residentialAddress.countryId});

            $('#firstName').focus();
            $("#mydropdownlist").val("thevalue");
        });

            $(".shipp-country-class").change(function(e){
                var countryId=$(".shipp-country-class").val();
                loadState("#{restEasyPath}/lookup/State/"+countryId+'/',"shipp" );
            });
            $(".resi-country-class").change(function(e){
            var countryId=$(".resi-country-class").val();
            loadState("#{restEasyPath}/lookup/State/"+countryId+'/',"resi" );
        });
    </script>
        </div>
    </ui:composition>
    </html>
```

Action class:

```
        @Name("userAction")
    @Stateless
    @AutoCreate
    public class UserActionImpl implements UserAction {

        @Out(value = "currentUser", scope = ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
        @In(value = "currentUser", scope = ScopeType.CONVERSATION, required = false)
        private CLRPUser currentUser;   

        @In
        private UserService userService;    

        @RequestParameter
        private Integer userId;

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8282995226262125676L;

        public String update() {
            userService.saveOrUpdate(currentUser);
            return "success";
        }

        public String getCLRP() {
            return Constants.SUCCESS_STR;
        }

        public CLRPUser getCurrentUser() {
            return currentUser;
        }

        public void setCurrentUser(CLRPUser currentUser) {
            this.currentUser = currentUser;
        }

    }
```

Service Class:

```
        @Name("userService")
    @Stateless
    @AutoCreate
    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @In
        private UserDAO userDAO;

        @In
        private LoggedInUser loggedInUser = null;

        public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
            return userDAO;
        }

        public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
            this.userDAO = userDAO;
        }

        public UserServiceImpl() {
            super();
        }

        public Integer saveOrUpdate(CLRPUser user) {
            user.setLastUpdatedBy(loggedInUser.getId());
            user.getResidentialAddress().setLastUpdatedBy(loggedInUser.getId());
            user.getShippingAddress().setLastUpdatedBy(loggedInUser.getId());
            user.getUserLogin().setLastUpdatedBy(loggedInUser.getId());
            user.getUserRoles().setLastUpdatedBy(loggedInUser.getId());
            // user.getTransaction().setLastUpdatedBy(loggedInUser.getId());

            UserEntity userEntity = UserMapper.mapUserEntity(user);
            Integer userId = userDAO.saveOrUpdate(userEntity);
            System.out.println("User Id saved " + userId);
            return userId;
        }

        }

    }
```

Mapper class:

```
        public class UserMapper {

        public static UserEntity mapUserEntity(CLRPUser user) {
            UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();

            userEntity.setUserId(user.getUserId());
            userEntity.setEmailAddress(user.getEmailAddress());
            userEntity.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
            userEntity.setLastName(user.getLastName());
            userEntity.setHomeNumber(user.getHomeNumber());
            userEntity.setOfficeNumber(user.getOfficeNumber());
            userEntity.setCellNumber(user.getCellNumber());
            userEntity.setCardId(user.getCardId());
            AuditInfo auditInfo = new AuditInfo();
            auditInfo.setLastUpdatedBy(user.getLastUpdatedBy());
            auditInfo.setLastUpdatedTime(user.getLastUpdatedTime());
            userEntity.setAuditInfo(auditInfo);
            userEntity.setType(user.getType());
            userEntity.setPreferenceId(user.getPreferenceId());
            userEntity.setASPCustomerId(user.getAspCustomerId());

            user.getResidentialAddress().setAddressType("R");
            user.getShippingAddress().setAddressType("S");

            AddressEntity residential = AddressMapper.mapAddressEntity(user
                    .getResidentialAddress());
            AddressEntity shipping = AddressMapper.mapAddressEntity(user
                    .getShippingAddress());
            List<AddressEntity> addressess = new ArrayList<AddressEntity>();
            addressess.add(residential);
            addressess.add(shipping);
            userEntity.setAddresses(new HashSet<AddressEntity>(addressess));

            user.getUserLogin().setUserID(user.getUserId());
            user.getUserLogin().setUserName(user.getCellNumber());
            user.getUserLogin().setPassword(user.getCellNumber());

            UserLoginEntity userlogin = UserLoginMapper.mapUserLoginEntity(user
                    .getUserLogin());
            List<UserLoginEntity> userlogins = new ArrayList<UserLoginEntity>();
            userlogins.add(userlogin);
            userEntity.setUserlogins(new HashSet<UserLoginEntity>(userlogins));

            user.getUserRoles().setUserId(user.getUserId());
            user.getUserRoles().setRoleID(1);

            UserRoleEntity userRoleEntity = UserRoleMapper.mapUserRoleEntity(user.getUserRoles());
            List<UserRoleEntity> roles = new ArrayList<UserRoleEntity>();
            roles.add(userRoleEntity);
            userEntity.setRoles(new HashSet<UserRoleEntity>(roles));

            return userEntity;
        }


    }
```

JPA_DAO class:

```
        @Name("userDAO")
    @Stateless
    @AutoCreate
    public class JPAUserDaoImpl implements UserDAO {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6173881454668735683L;

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "clrp")
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

        public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
            this.entityManager = em;
        }


        public Integer saveOrUpdate(UserEntity newUser) {
            entityManager.merge(newUser);
            return newUser.getUserId();
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Error is: Exception during request processing:
`Caused by javax.servlet.ServletException with message: "#{userAction.update}: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException" 
   at com.ermms.clrp.user.UserActionImpl.update(UserActionImpl.java:50)` Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException `at com.ermms.clrp.service.UserServiceImpl.saveOrUpdate(UserServiceImpl.java:59)
`

Comment: What do you have in `UserServiceImpl.java:59` that is throwing a `NullPointerException`?